# Shopify Input Value Is Overidden Somehow

Tags: html, input, shopify, liquid

If you have any input on what's going on here I sure would appreciate it. When I add more than one variant, my *quantity input* breaks.

**I have a Shopify product with only ONE variant here:**

https://three-main.myshopify.com/products/copy-of-liquid-hand-soap

**I have essentially the same product duplicated, but with TWO variants here:**

https://three-main.myshopify.com/products/liquid-hand-soap

**Note:**
If you're looking closely you'll see the input populate correctly for a split second, then revert to the broken input field that says "add to cart" instead of "1". Is there something I should be doing to populate individual inputs when there's more than one variant?

**This is the code we're using to populate the quantity box:**

```
<div class="di-quantity-wrap">
                  <label
                    class="product-quantity-label"
                    for="quantity">    
                    Quantity:
                  </label>
                  <input
                    class="input-field product-quantity-input"
                    type="text"
                    name="quantity"
                    value="1">
                </div>
```

Thank you in advance!